# If either one of both equals

Tags: php, date, datetime, calendar, logical-operators

have start and end dates which are stored in a database in this format:

```
start date= 20121004     //4th October 2012
end date= 20121004     //16th November 2012
```

so I can use date format:

```
$date = date("Ymd"); // returns: 20121004
```

to determine when to display and not display

to repopulate my update input boxes I use:

```
$start=(str_split($stdate,4));// START DATE: splits stored date into 2x4 ie: 20121209 = 2012 1209
$syr =  $start[0];// re first half ie: 2012 which is the year
$start2 = $start[1];//re second half ie: 1209
$start3=(str_split($start2,2));// splits second half date into 2x2 ie: 1209 = 12 09
$smth = $start3[0]; // first half = month ie: 12
$sday = $start3[1];  // second half = day ie: 09
$expiry=(str_split($exdate,4)); ///SAME AGAIN FOR EXPIRY DATE ...
$xyr =  $expiry[0];
$expiry2 = $expiry[1];
$expiry3=(str_split($expiry2,2));
$xmth = $expiry3[0]; 
$xday = $expiry3[1];
```

which works fine but I need to repopulate the input boxes for the month showing the date in the database like this

```
<option value="01">January</option`>
```

using

```
if ($smth==01):$month='January'; endif;
if ($xmth==01):$month='January'; endif;
// if the start and/or expiry month number = 01 display $month as January
if ($smth==02):$smonth='February'; endif;
if ($xmth==02):$smonth='February'; endif;
if ($smth==03):$month='March'; endif;

<select name="stmonth" class="input">
<option value="<?=$smth?>"><?=$month?></option>
...
</select>
```

is there an easier way to display IF EITHER ONE EQUALS rather than having to write the same line twice once for each **$smth** AND **$xmth** ?
re: `if ($smth **and or** $xmth ==01):$month='January'; endif;`

======================UPDATE====================
Found a simpler way to display without using nested if loops. unrelated to original question but may be useful to someone:

```
$months = array(X,January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December);
```

///first record dummy to keep code more relative

```
//simple swith command
switch ($smth){
case 1: $s = 1; break;
case 2: $s = 2; break;
case 3: $s = 3; break;
case 4: $s = 4; break;
case 5: $s = 5; break;
case 6: $s = 6; break;
case 7: $s = 7; break;
case 8: $s = 8; break;
case 9: $s = 9; break;
case 10: $s = 10; break;
case 11: $s = 11; break;
case 12: $s = 12; break;
default; }
switch ($xmth){
case 1: $x = 1; break;
case 2: $x = 2; break;
case 3: $x = 3; break;
case 4: $x = 4; break;
case 5: $x = 5; break;
case 6: $x = 6; break;
case 7: $x = 7; break;
case 8: $x = 8; break;
case 9: $x = 9; break;
case 10: $x = 10; break;
case 11: $x = 11; break;
case 12: $x = 12; break;
default; }
```

then display like this:

```
<select name="stmonth" class="input">
<option value="<?=$smth?>"><?=$months[$s]?></option>
```

Comment: Using `DateTime` objects will save you a lot of headache.

Answer (score 1):

`if( statement || statement)` will pass if either statement is true.

```
if( $smth == 1 || $xmth == 1)
```

Note that numbers with a leading `0` are considered octal numbers, so `09` will become `0` since `9` is not a valid octal digit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an OR statement is what you're looking for.

`if ($smth == 1 || $xmth == 1)`

Please read about [PHP Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

There is an AND if they both had to be correct, instead of using nested `if` statements you would use:

```
if(something && somethinelse) {
    //do this 
}
```

instead of:

```
if(something) { 
    if(somethingelse) {
       //do this
 }
```